# How to zoom in map with HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to achieve what the following website has: http://clicky.com/stats/?site_id=32020#/stats/locale-map?site_id=32020

You can double click on a country then view that country's states/provinces on the map. This is a really neat feature however I cannot find docs regarding it.

The normal world map looks like this:
http://www.highcharts.com/studies/world-map.htm

So how can I add this 'zooming' functionality which allows me to view sub-states in countries?

Answer (score 1):

At this moment maps are only beta project, all of studies are available here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/studies. You can try to catch click event on SVG element, and then load "new map" to achieve similar effect.